# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ if $a_0=a,a_1=b$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

How can I find the limit of the following recursive formula?

> $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $a_0=a; a_1=b; a_n= \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$
>
> $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{a_n} = ?$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjkw5H2-JHPAhXl6YMKHWlTBIQQFghFMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dma.ulpgc.es%2Fprofesores%2Fpersonal%2Faph%2Fficheros%2Finvestigacion%2Fficheros%2Fmm_16_2.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFTaU2AXtZEqlPc-G6T_tLrxQHyvg

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276402/limit-of-sequence-in-which-each-term-is-defined-by-the-average-of-preceding-two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think what happens if $a=0$, $b=1$. You can draw a line and see what happens, by drawing the points of the sequence
$$0,1,1/2,3/4,5/8,11/16,\ldots$$
In other words, we start at zero, go $1$ unit to the rigth, $1/2$ unit to the left, $1/4$ of unit to the right, $1/8$ unit to the left, $\ldots$, $1/2^n$ unit to the left, is $n$ is odd and to the right if $n$ is odd.

This gives us the formula (in the case $a=0$, $b=1$)
$$a_0=0,\qquad a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-2^{-1})^i$$
therefore the limit point is $\lim a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-2^{-1})^i=\frac{1}{1-(-2^{-1})}=\frac{2}{3}$.

In the case of general $a$ and $b$, we are not working on the unit interval, but rather on an interval of length $(b-a)$, and $a$ units to the right (left? Anyway...), so scaling gives us, for general $a$ and $b$,
$$\lim a_n=a+\frac{2}{3}(b-a)=\frac{a+2b}{3}$$

If you want to be formal in the general case, show by induction that $a_n=a+(b-a)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-2^{-1})^i$.

Answer (score 4):

I learned to solve these using linear algebra.

$\begin {bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac 12 &\frac 12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_n\\a_n-1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin {bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac 12 &\frac 12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_0\end{bmatrix}$

diagonalize the matrix

$\begin {bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \frac 13\begin{bmatrix}1 &-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& (-\frac 12)^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2 &1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b\\a\end{bmatrix}$

We an apply the limit here, and and take $n$ to infinty.  It will reduce the algebra that follows, but it is worth seeing how to come up with a general fromula for $a_n$

$\begin {bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \frac 13\begin{bmatrix}1 &-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& (-\frac 12)^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2b+a\\-b+a\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin {bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n\end{bmatrix} = \frac 13\begin{bmatrix}1 
&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2b+a\\(-\frac 12)^n(-b+a)\end{bmatrix}$

$a_n = \frac 13 (2b+a + 2(-\frac12)^n(-b+a))$

As $n$ goes to infnity $\frac 13 (2b+a)$

Comment: In the end it should be $\frac{1}{3}(2b+a)$ (it's just a typo).